# Processing .CSV files in Azure ADF (ignoring tailiing dates in filename)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF package setup in Azure. There are 25 files that i am connecting to using the dataset setup in ADF. There are 25 connections, 1 connection to each .CSV file (the .CSV files will include a date in the filename of the .CSV i.e. Campus20-02-24.csv. I would like to know in Azure ADF how i can ignore the 20-02-24 and just have a connection to the file as Campus.csv. All of the files sit in a blob container; the ADF solution points to the blob container and processes the file. I would like to ignore the date in the file name and only process .CSV files where the name is like Campus*.csv for example? Is this possible?

I am expecting if the file arrives in the blob container as Campus20-02-24.csv, or Campus21-02-24.csv then i would like to have my dedicated dataset in the ADF package for Campus to process it or identify it as Campus.csv OR perhaps even if its possible to rename the file to Campus.csv before processing because the fixed connection on the data set is looking for Campus.csv, not Campus20-02-24.csv for example.

Here is an image of the setup of the dataset that connects to the Campus.csv file.

[Dataset image setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGJq5.png)

I then have a dataflow setup for each file, so focusing on the Campus.csv file, looks like this

[Data flow Image setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMA5S.png)

In the pipeline, I have a data flow connection and copy data activity for each file. the image below shows the Campus data flow and copy data for this (this just extracts the records from the Campus SQL table to Parquet file.

[Pipeline Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyHtI.png)

I would just like to know the least intrusive way to be able to load the Campus.csv file even if the file comes into the container like Campus20-02-24.csv, I want to be able to process anything like Campus*.csv.....

Answer (score 0):

As your source files are from Blob container, you can use **[Storage event triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory)** in ADF.

Use dataset parameters for the filename of the source dataset and target dataset.

First, create a string type parameter in the dataset and use in the filename of the source like below.

[image]

[image]

Similarly, do the same for the target dataset.

Now, in the pipeline, create a pipeline parameter of string type.

[image]

Now, take a copy activity with source and target datasets and use this pipeline parameter for the dataset parameters of the source and target datasets.

[image]

Do the same in the sink of the copy activity as well.

Now, create a storage event trigger for this pipeline. Give the storage account, container name and in the **Blob path begins with** option, give `Campus` word. In the **Blob paths ends with** option, give `.csv` like below.

[image]

Click on **continue** and at the end of the trigger creation, it will ask the value of the parameter. Here, provide the trigger parameter `@triggerBody().fileName` to that like below.

[image]

Click on **OK** and publish both pipeline and trigger. So, whenever a new file with a name of `Campus*.csv` uploaded to your Blob container, the trigger will run the pipeline and the file will be copied to the target location like below.

[image]

This pipeline design is for the daily loading files. To copy the already existing 25 files to the target location, use wild card file path `Campus*.csv` in the copy activity source like below.

[image]

Comment: This is a great source of information, however my intention here is to no trigger a pipeline to run. We will run the pipelines specifically once per day. The pipeline has 25 copy data activities which process 25 CSV files. The Pipelines will only be run once per day. So when there is a Campus02-20-24.csv sitting in the blob container that the dataset currently points too, The dataset currently only connects to the actual file name i.e. Campus.csv - I want it to be able to connect to any (and there will only be an instance of 1 x Campus file in the directory) Campus*.csv file and process it.

Comment: Then use wild card file path `Campus*.csv` as I mentioned in the last. No need to take 25 copy activities for this. A single copy activity with wild card file path will copy all the required files to the target location. Leave the target file path empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wildcard file path in copy activity if you want to process all the files starting with particular string like 'campus_2024_01_01.csv' etc with pattern as 'campus*'.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution. I just used a standard data set to point to the container and use the wildcard path in pipline copy data activity to pickup anything like Campus20????????.csv which works well. the '20" will be the starting year and the 8 characters will be the date tailed onto the file name.